# Computing covariance for independently distributed uniform variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ ~ Uniform(0,1).

How does one set up the computation for $\textrm{Cov}(X^2Y,Y^2Z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) and the independence,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}[X^2Y,Y^2Z]
&=\operatorname E[X^2Y^3Z]-\operatorname E[X^2Y]\operatorname E[Y^2Z]\\
&=\operatorname EX^2\operatorname EY^3\operatorname EZ-\operatorname EX^2\operatorname EY\operatorname EY^2\operatorname EZ.
\end{align*}
Hence, we need to calculate the first three moments of the uniform distribution.

Comment: The $n$th moment about zero for a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is $\frac1{n+1}$